# Remove multiple substring from a string Python

Tags: python, string

I want to replace multiple substrings in a single string, and I want to know what approach is most efficient / best practice.

I've tried using str.replace() and it works but that seems inefficient. I'm running Python 3.6, so I'd like a solution compatible with that.

For some context here, I want to create the name of a (new) class from some text I read. So I need to convert text to (strings for) valid Python identifiers (e.g., "bad-Classname's" becomes "badClassnames"). So while my question of the best way to replace multiple substrings in a single string still stands, if there is a better way to convert text to class names I'd be happy to hear that too.

My existing code is as follows:

```py
my_str = my_str.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("'", "").replace("-", "").replace("’", "")
```

Is there a better way to do this? Regular expressions, a for loop, some builtin string method that I didn't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly with regexp substitution:

```
import re

my_str = "bad-Classname's"
my_str = re.sub(r"[ ,/'’-]", "", my_str)
print(my_str)   # badClassnames
```

---

- `[ ,/'’-]` - regex character class, matches a single character in the list  "`,/'’-`"

Answer (score 2):

#### use str.translate()

```
# this line builds the translation table
# and can be done once
table = str.maketrans({c:'' for c in " ,/'-’"})

my_str = "bad-Classname's"

# this line does the replacement
my_str = my_str.translate(table)

print(my_str)   
# >>> badClassnames
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']

In [1]: [x for x in string.split() if x not in {'is', 'this', 'a', 'string'}]
Out[1]: ['test']
```

Hope this answers your query.